# Fourier and $Z$ transform of a signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

We have $$X(k)=4[u(k-2)-u(k)* d(k-3)]$$

I need to find the Fourier transform,$Z$ transform,as well as dhe magnitude and phase spectra.

First of all I think that I need to convert the $u(k)$ and $u(k-2)$ to $d(k)$.Then find $Z$ transform.Then study the region of convergence of the $Z$ transform,to determine if the fourier transform exists.How do I do all these steps?By the way,I dont have any idea about the magnitude/phase

Note :$u(k)* d(k-3)]$ is the convolution of u(k) and d(k-3),not the multiplication of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by $d(k)$ you mean the discrete delta impulse $\delta(k)$. By noting that

$$f(k)*\delta(k-l)=f(k-l)$$

for any sequence $f(k)$, the signal $x(k)$ can be written as

$$x(k)=4[u(k-2)-u(k-3)]=4\delta(k-2)$$

The $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $X(k)$ is then simply

$$X(z)=4z^{-2}$$

which converges anywhere except for $z=0$, i.e. its region of convergence is $|z|>0$. Since the region of convergence includes the unit circle, the Fourier transform of $x(k)$ exists and is simply given by $X(z)$ with $z=e^{j\omega}$:

$$X(e^{j\omega})=4e^{-2j\omega}$$

The magnitude is $|X(e^{j\omega})|=4$, and the phase is $\arg\{X(e^{j\omega})\}=-2\omega$.

Comment: I understand the solution,thank you.I have one question. How do we know that $$f(k)*\delta(k-l)=f(k-l)$$ ? Is it a property of a theorem?

Comment: @fsdd: It is a property of the delta impulse. $f(k)*\delta(k)=f(k)$ and $f(k)*\delta(k-l)=f(k-l)$. Convolution with a delta impulse basically copies the original sequence to the location of the delta impulse.